# Tradução para Português de "de-escalate"

Tags: tradução-inglês

É muito comum em Inglês ouvir-se a expressão "de-escalate", principalmente quando se trata de potenciais situações de conflito, ou seja, a expressão faz referência a técnicas que servem para baixar os ânimos em situações de tensão e/ou propensas à violência. Algumas referências [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=deescalate%20violence).

Alguém tem referências ou quer sugerir possíveis traduções para Português? O Lingue dá [algumas sugestões](https://www.linguee.pt/ingles-portugues/traducao/de-escalate.html), mas todas muito fracas.

Comment: Para a pergunta ficar ótima, devias ter algumas frases exemplo - como o Rye pôs na resposta dele. :)

Answer (score 2):

Para uma tradução literal, sugiro algo como diminuir/reduzir/parar a "**escalada de violência"** (deixo [aqui](https://www.dn.pt/mundo/escalada-de-violencia-em-gaza-causou-pelo-menos-25-mortos-10865028.html) um exemplo de uso da expresão).

No entanto, neste contexto, podemos ainda utilizar os verbos "atenuar" e "amenizar" como substitutos, sem perda de significado. Alguns exemplos para referência:

> O exército interviu numa tentativa de diminuir a escalada de violência na região.
>
> Foi necessário amenizar os ânimos, de modo a evitar um conflito.
>
> A situação parecia perigosa, mas acabou por ser atenuada.

Comment: A resposta é interessante, mas acho que pode ser muito melhorada. "De-escalate" é um antónimo de "escalate". "Diminuir a escalada de violência" não é um antónimo de "escalar a violência".

Comment: Concordo, mas não existe, tanto quanto sei, nenhum equivalente direto na língua portuguesa, daí ter sugerido aquilo que é a tradução mais próxima (e mais utilizada nos meios de comunicação social) - diminuir/impedir a escalada de violência.

Comment: de facto o cerne da questão resume-se a encontrar um antónimo para _escalar_

Answer (score 2):

O mais comum provavelmente é

- reverter/evitar a escalada,
- acalmar,

mas há uma tradução direta:

- [desescalar](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/desescalar)
  *reduzir a intensidade de um conflito ou de situação bélica*.

Comment: Interessante, mas a definição do Priberam está errada: `Parar o que estava rápida e progressivamente maior ou mais intenso (ex.: as negociações desescalaram a tensão na região; o preço da habitação começa a desescalar)`. Não é apenas parar ou evitar a escalada, mas baixar.

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Concordo. Substitui pela da Porto Editora.